# Tikz generated PDF produces ? when citing references

Tags: tikz-pgf, bibtex

I am trying to generate a PDF figure on the fly using TikZ (code below). The figure references from my .bib file and so when I run pdflatex the first time, the PDF gets generated with ?

```
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \tikzsetnextfilename{results}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar width=20pt,     
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Power Saving (\%)},
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 100,
    xtick=data,
    ytick=\empty,
    symbolic x coords={image,video},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
    \addplot [style={fill=rred}] coordinates {(image,60) (video,57)};
    \addplot [style={fill=mygreen}] coordinates {(image,52) (video,48)};
    \addplot [style={fill=royalblue}] coordinates {(image,66) (video,52)};
    \legend{~\cite{A},~\cite{B},C}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Average power saving. Higher is better}
    \label{fig:results}
    \end{figure}
```

My make file has the following sequence of compile code

```
    pdflatex -shell-escape ... 
    bibtex ...
    pdflatex -shell-escape ...
```

Any idea how to work around getting the citations into my pdf figure

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try compiling again.

Comment: I see that you're using the externalisation library.  That causes issues with references - have you read the section in the manual about how to enable them?

Comment: @Loop Space : I read the manual and it mentions something about using make or list. I tried adding make -f <file>.makefile -j 2 to my Makefile but I get an error that such a file does not exist. I don't think I quite understood how to use make or list in this flow.

Comment: I opened up the .dpth file and manually run the command pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figs/results" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{<file>}\input{<file>}" and that generates the pdf correctly but am unable to do so otherwise.

Comment: A complete example would make it easier.

Comment: The citations are in the pdf figure due to the \cite{} in the legend. Try replacing these with author/name to fit your need for a description in the legend.

Comment: Makefiles ar highly customized. An example of a makefile that I use for my own writing can be found here: https://github.com/rvaneijk/lean-LaTex-approach

Comment: Since you use `bibtex` to compile the bibliography you have to specify `backend=bibtex` in the bib latex options, i.e., `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,...]{biblatex}`, otherwise, by default, bib latex requires `biber`.

Answer (score 2):

In the legend, you are using a `\cite`. So the question mark during the first run is not surprising.

Seems you have to hardcode your legend adding `Uthor, A (2016)`.